# Restric public access wampserver 2.1

Tags: wampserver

I'm using WampServer 2.1 and I want to give some restrictions on my WampServer localhost, but the problem is that when I put my code in httpd.config and restart the services, the icon won't turn green after I edit it.

Here's my code:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```